# spherical harmonic function in boost

Tags: math, opengl, boost, 3d

I would like to use spherical harmonics to represent a spherical function. I found out that the boost library provides functionality to generate the basis functions, which can be found at

> boost/math/special_functions/spheric_harmonic.hpp.

The prototype is

```
spherical_harmonic_r(unsigned n, int m, T1 theta, T2 phi, const Policy&);
```

I want to figure out the meaning of phi. Imagine a right-handed coordinate system same as used in OpenGL(+Y up, +X right, +Z out), is phi the angle that starts from +Z and goes counter-clockwise as seen from +Y.

Comment: Usually theta = colatitude (i.e. 0 = north, pi = south); phi = longitude (i.e. 0 = line @ x = 0, pi = same line but opposite side). So phi should be the angle which starts from +Y and goes ccw as seen from Z+.

Comment: @sbabbi From your description "phi = longitude (i.e. 0 = line @ x = 0, pi = same line but opposite side)", it is more appropriate to say that phi starts from +X and goes ccw as seen from +Y.